# SchemaLocation must have even number of URI's

Tags: xml, webservice, soapui

Estoy creando una factura electronica pero en la validacion de la misma me dice que tiene este errorr:

> Error en la línea (2): SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value =
>   'http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1
>   ../xsd/DIAN_UBL.xsd
>   urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2
>   ../../ubl2/common/UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule-2.0.xsd
>   urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2
>   ../../ubl2/common/UBL-QualifiedDatatypes- 2.0.xsd' must have even
>   number of URI's.

Alguien sabe a que se debe ese error.

Comment: Buen día según veo en la traza de error tienes un problema con el contrato de tu ws, si te esta generando inconvenientes con xsd puedes revisar haciendo el llamado con el wsdl y validar los parámetros que le remites correspondan con los que tienes que enviar. Saludos

Comment: @JoseReynel gracias, segun me comentas el problema no esta entonces en modificar esa linea en mi XML, es decir cambiar todo esto: 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1
../xsd/DIAN_UBL_v1_0_fos.xsd
urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2
../../ubl2/common/UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule-2.0.xsd
urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2
../../ubl2/common/UBL-QualifiedDatatypes-2.0.xsd">

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que donde se construyen los xsd, que es en tu caso el contrato para el uso del servicio valida que se esté construyendo correctamente... revisando veo que existe una pregunta hecha que tiene caracteristicas similares a la tuya, te comparto la URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662953/error-schemalocation-value-must-have-even-number-of-uris-on-namespaces